# Pass end point details in Rest Web Service command in Automation Anywhere

Tags: automationanywhere

In the **Rest Webservice Command**, I don't see any option to pass a variable in the URI.

We do not want to hard the end point in the script.

As an e.g I will want the script to use different points for dev/stage and prod.

Is there a work around for this.

On building a URI with variables like :
**https://$v_hostname$/test-rs-v1/employee/data** send request works fine but
bot runs we get an error stating :

**Hostname could not be parsed.**

Comment: What are the client version and editions?

Comment: its 10.5.9.Its not supported in that version

Comment: Yes, that version has a bug and they fixed it on version 11.3.1 https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v11.3/page/topics/release-notes/release-notes-11-3-1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** That was a bug and fixed on version 11.3.1. You can only achieve that on version 11.3.1 or later.

**Reference:** https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v11.3/page/topics/release-notes/release-notes-11-3-1.html

**Workaround for older versions (If you have experience with C#):** [Build and test DLLs](https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v11.3/page/topics/aae-developer/aae-build-and-test-dlls.html)

---

**The following applies only on version 11.3.1 and later.**
Make sure that **$v_hostname$** contains a value at the run time, using debugging option or message box command.
I did reproduce the same error by entering a variable that doesn't exist or doesn't have a value, there is no another scenario would reproduce "Hostname could not be parsed".

If the hostname/URL is invalid you will get **"The remote name could not be resolved:"**.

I've tested the **REST Web Service** command on both community and enterprise editions, and it's working very well.